# Getting properties of keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a `key/value` array that I defined by doing something similar to:

```
var arr;

function assign(iSize, jSize)
{
    arr = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < jSize; j++) {
            var pt = new Point(i, j);
            arr[pt] = [1, 2, 3];
        }
    }
}
```

Where my `Point` function is

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

and now I would like to iterate through all the values of the array but I also need to know the keys as well. I've tried

```
function iterate() {
    for(var e in arr) {
        console.log(e.x);
    }
}
```

but it just prints out `undefined`. Also, if I try

```
function iterate() {
    console.log(Object.keys(arr));
}
```

I just get `[object Object]` as output.

I've tried printing out the `Point` at the moment of creation and I can access the `x` and `y` values just fine.

As a side note, in my actual implementation I'm not just assigning the array `[1, 2, 3]` to each index of my array. I am assigning an array generated by another function that has nothing to do with accessing the keys in `arr`

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(arr),null,4));`

Comment: All object properties/keys are strings or [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), when you try to use an `object` as a key, it is coerced to the string `[object object]`. I suggest to create a `toString()` method in your point class. Or to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared), Maps allow using objects as the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All object `keys` are `strings` or [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). So, when you try to use an `object` as the `key` of another `object` it is coerced to the string `[object object]` using the [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method. You can check it on the next example:

```js
let obj = {a: "something"};
console.log(obj.toString());
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

One solution for what you want to do is to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

> The `keys` of an `Object` are **String** and **Symbol**, whereas they can be **any value** for a `Map`, including functions, **objects**, and any primitive.

## Example with `Map`

```js
function Point(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var arr;

function assign(iSize, jSize)
{
    arr = new Map();

    for (var i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < jSize; j++)
        {
            var pt = new Point(i, j);
            arr.set(pt, [1, 2, 3]);
        }
    }
}

function iterate()
{
    arr.forEach((val, key) =>
    {
        console.log("key => ", JSON.stringify(key), " val => ", JSON.stringify(val));
    });
}

assign(2, 2);
iterate();
```

Another solution is to add a `toString()` method into your **Point** class to avoid calling the `Object.prototype.toString()` one, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Overriding_the_default_toString_method):

## Example with `toString()`

```js
function Point(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// New toString() method for the Point class.

Point.prototype.toString = function()
{
    return `(${this.x},${this.y})`;
}

var arr;

function assign(iSize, jSize)
{
    arr = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < jSize; j++)
        {
            var pt = new Point(i, j);
            arr[pt] = [1, 2, 3];
        }
    }
}

function iterate()
{
    for (const key in arr)
    {
        console.log("key => ", key, " val => ", JSON.stringify(arr[key]));
    }
}

assign(2, 2);
iterate();
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I went with a Map approach and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem it's `arr[pt] = [1, 2, 3];`. When you use `var pt = new Point(i, j);`
result of new Point(i, j) it object `{x:i, y:j}`

When you try to use object as another object's key (`arr[pt] = [1, 2, 3];`) engine understand it like `arr[pt.toString()]` because `typeof pt === 'object'`

just use another key in `arr[pt]`

If you really need to use object as a key you can write your own toString for Point. Something like:

```
Point.prototype.toString = function pointToString() {
  var ret = JSON.stringify(this);
  return ret;
}
```

And then use it

```
function iterate(){
    for(var e in arr){
        console.log(JSON.parse(e).x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you use an object (Point) as key. If you save a reference to this object and then use it as a key you get your property (last property in code introduced by me). Do you really need Point object as key?

```
var arr;
var ptRef;
function assign(iSize, jSize) {
  arr = {};
  ptRef = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < jSize; j++) {
      var pt = new Point(i, j);
      console.log(pt);
      arr[pt] = [1, 2, 3];
      ptRef = pt;
    }
  }
  console.log(arr[ptRef]);
}
```